# How to make setInterval of a progress bar work when a tab is inactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can see there are a couple of similar questions asked here but unfortunately I couldn't find the answer I expect.
I am quite new to Programming and trying my hands on Javascript Progress Bar. I have a counter to countdown whenever the progress bar runs out of width but i got the problem, when the tab in focus is inactive, the progress bar pauses thereby keeping counter not to countdown.
I got the idea of using web workers http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_workers.htm but I couldn't get that to work. I would appreciate any form of help I get here.
Below is my Code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script 
           src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/
           jquery.min.js">
       </script>
    <style>
        #progressContainer {
            position: relative;
            width: 97%;
            height: 25px;
            background-color: #ddd;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
        #progressBar {
            position: absolute;
            width: 0%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #A9A9A9;
        }
        #container{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#countDownBtn").click(function(){

                var cdNumber = $("#countDownId").val();
                var id = setInterval(frame, 100);
                var elem = document.getElementById("progressBar");
                var progressBarWidth = 101;

                function frame() {                 

                    if (progressBarWidth === 0) {
                        clearInterval(id);
                        cdNumber--;                     
                        $("#countDownId").val(cdNumber);
                        console.log(cdNumber);

                        if (cdNumber === 0) {
                            clearInterval(id);          
                        }
                        else {
                            elem.style.width = '100%';
                            progressBarWidth = 100;
                            //alert("Hi");
                        }   
                    } 
                    else {
                        progressBarWidth--;
                        elem.style.width = progressBarWidth + '%';
                    }         
                }                    
            });
        });
    </script>

   </head>
   <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="countDownId" value="">
            <button id="countDownBtn" class="btn">Click</button>
        </div><br>
        <div id="progressContainer">
        <div id="progressBar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: a) avoid setInterval and use requestionAnimationFrame or setTimeout instead, and b) it's largely down to each browser to manage what happens when you change to a different tab. You may have to refresh your status based on time elapsed when the tab becomes active again.

Comment: Big question may be: Why would you do that? :) Also if you want to learn programming you may use TypeScript instead which compiles to JavaScript. You will learn a "real" programming language syntax then similar to Java or C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll always run into such problems when depending on the precision of some interval; even `requestAnimationFrame`. They ain't precise.

The better approach *(not just in this case, but pretty much every time you have to transition a value over time)* is to save the startTime and compute the passed time in the interval (as @Nosyara already suggested).

When dealing with scaling-factors and/or pausing of this stuff, things can get messy again. Here a utility for this task:

```
// The basic concept of this "Clock" is a linear equation over Date.now()
// plus the logic to make this equation pausable.
// therefore it's completely independant of **any** interval; it's just math.
function Clock(v){
    var p=true,m=1,b=+v||0,n=Clock.now;
    return Object.assign(Object.create(Clock.prototype),{
        // getter() / setter(value)
        // I don't use real getter and setter, because this syntax 
        // allows/implements method-chaining
        value(v){return arguments.length?(b=(+v||0)-(!p&&m*n()),this):b+(!p&&m*n())},
        speed(v){return arguments.length?(v=+v||0,p||v===m||(b+=n()*(m-v)),m=v,this):m},
        paused(v){return arguments.length?(((v=!!v)===p)||(b+=n()*((p=v)?m:-m)),this):p},
    });
}
Object.assign(Clock.prototype,{
    valueOf(){return this.value()},
    //aliases for setting the paused() state; doesn't matter if you call them repeatedly.
    start(){return this.paused(false)},
    stop(){return this.paused(true)},
});
Clock.now=Date.now; //the function used for timing
//Clock.now=performance&&performance.now?performance.now.bind(performance):Date.now;
```

Now to your code:

```
$(function(){
    function frame(){
        //yes, countDown get's converted to Number
        var value = Math.max(0, countDown);
        var count = Math.ceil(value);
        var progress = value % 1;

        $progressBar.width( progress * 100 + "%" );

        //so that I don't update $countDown.val() on every frame, but only if necessary
        //on the other hand, it wouldn't be that bad.
        if(count !== lastCount) $countDown.val( lastCount = count );

        //either stop the countDown or request the next frame.
        if(value > 0) requestAnimationFrame(frame);
        else countDown.stop();
    }

    //create a Clock and set speed. Clock is paused by default.
    var countDown = Clock().speed( -1 / 10000/*ms*/ );

    var $progressBar = $("#progressBar");
    var $countDown = $("#countDownId");
    var lastCount;

    $("#countDownBtn").click(function(){
        //if !countDown.paused() then there already is a pending `requestAnimationFrame(frame)`
        //from the last call of frame()
        if(countDown.paused()) requestAnimationFrame(frame);

        countDown.value( $countDown.val() ).start();
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems in one of my projects in Chrome browser.  The root of problem, that Chrome allows up to 1 timer event per second (setTimeout or setInterval) if tab is not active. In case there more than 1 call per second - it creates queue, than behavior of page depends on logic inside events and may look not as expected. One of solutions is to check visibility of the page and manage intervals [Check here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-page-visibility-20110602/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout instead and use recursion. It could look something like this:

```
var stopInterval = false;
frame();

function frame() {
    if(stopInterval) return;

    // Your stuff to run in interval HERE

    setTimeout(frame, 100);
}
```

Webworkers are not supported in older browsers. Also browsers specify how they handle setTimeout and setInterval on inactive tab individually, so the behavior may differ. Chrome seems to slow down the recursion alot (1 per second?).

Comment: It will not work in chrome. The function will work 1 time per second.

Answer (score 0):

As @ManoDestra pointed out in the comment, you should use requestAnimationFrame instead of setInterval.

The best solution I would propose is utilizing the HTML5 Visibility API to detect when a tab becomes active again after being inactive, and then update the progress bar accordingly. Perhaps you could store the timestamp of the countdown when it is initialized, and when the tab becomes active again, you look at the new timestamp and make a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in your case you can use clock time to represent right progress. When you don't want trust browser about interval events.
Let say you want 10 sec countdown:

```
var tm = new Date().getTime() + 10000; // 10 sec in milliseconds
setInterval(function(){
    var secondsPassed = (tm - new Date().getTime()) / 1000;
    // update UI 
}, 100); // You can use variable here in different visibility modes
```